# How to determine the size of var?

Tags: c#

I Have a variable declared as follows:

```
var a = 99494;
```

Then I used the following to determine the size of the variable in bytes:

```
Marshal.SizeOf(a)
```

Does it get the actual size of memory occupied by this value ?

Comment: `var` is just "I don't want to write the type of this variable. Compiler, please do that work and pretend I wrote the type instead".

Comment: The actual code will be compiled as though you wrote `int a = 99494;` since `99494` is of type `int`.

Comment: `int size = sizeof(a);` since `99494` is of type `int` (`Int32`) it takes **32** bits = **4** bytes

Answer (score 10):

> Does it get the actual size of memory occupied by this value ?

Yes. In this case it is fairly simple, since the `var` is an `int`. It will always yield the same value (4). (`var` isn't a dynamic type, it is determined on compile time.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, var is just a compile time trick so the compiler will decide it's type at compile time. I wouldn't recommend using it besides obvious and very long class names. e.g `var x = new BigBigBigClass()`. It makes your code less readable to others and makes it easier to make mistakes. C# is a statically typed language and while it takes a few more seconds to declare types, it pays off when you aren't accidentally mixing classes

Since the compiler will put x as an int, it should return 32 bits (4 bytes) as that's the size of a standard int

Comment: Why shouldn't you use `var`? You didn't give any reason for your recommendation. I would remove that part from your answer since it doesn't have anything to do with the question asked.

Comment: There is no point in discussing whether to use `var` or not, there are few cases where you *must* use `var`, other than that the usage is just an opinion.

Comment: well explained answer!

Comment: There is nothing explained regarding the question asked. The recommendation is incorrect at some places, so I wouldn't say it is particularly well-explained.

Comment: I would argue `var` makes code more readable by driving you to come up with better naming. Also am not sure about the "easier to make mistakes" part, since compiler won't allow you, plus the VS code analysis would underline the "mistake" with red even before you hit build. As mentioned previously, it's just opinion based at best

Comment: I disagree on the point about var - refactoring is significantly easier when you can switch a factory to return an interface instead of an implementation without having to go through everywhere that consumes it to update variable types. Life is easier for the developer, and type safety is preserved by the compiler - it’s win-win